# Is it possible to run a batch read in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

On [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices) page under "API calls" it says:
*Use batch operations for your **reads**, writes, and deletes instead of single operations. Batch operations are more efficient because they perform multiple operations with the same overhead as a single operation.*

However, when I look through the documentation I do not see any reference to how I could do batch reads with Google Cloud Datastore. Am I misinterpreting the documentation or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations) examples on how to execute batch operations in Datastore. For example look at this :

```
FullEntity<IncompleteKey> task1 = FullEntity.newBuilder(keyFactory.newKey())
.set("category", "Personal")
.set("done", false)
.set("priority", 4)
.set("description", "Learn Cloud Datastore")
.build();
FullEntity<IncompleteKey> task2 = Entity.newBuilder(keyFactory.newKey())
    .set("category", "Personal")
    .set("done", false)
    .set("priority", 5)
    .set("description", "Integrate Cloud Datastore")
    .build();
List<Entity> tasks = datastore.add(task1, task2);
Key taskKey1 = tasks.get(0).getKey();
Key taskKey2 = tasks.get(1).getKey();
```

I also found a nice [article](https://medium.com/@duhroach/datastore-transactions-batching-898fd695d754) about batching and transactions in Datastore if you want to read it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any examples batch reading?
For example, if I wanted to get all elements with a property `url` and value `https://www.google.com` or `https://www.facebook.com` or `https://www.apple.com`.

Is it possible to do this with just one api call?

Comment: As Andrei [shared](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-batch-lookup-code-sample) you can check the read section. I think there you can find all the possible ways you can read/get from Datastore.